# How to iterate a flask output list in html?

Tags: python, html, flask

I am writing a flask app and can display results on the browser using the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> {{ title }} </title>
</head>
   <body>
    Enter starter data to execute:
      <form action="/top_hits" method="POST">

        <input type="text" name="text" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit!" rows="6"/>


      </form>

    {% for q in q1 %}
        ​<textarea form="txtArea" name="q" class="form-control" id="q" rows="100" cols="60" placeholder="{{ q }}" style="font-size: 15pt"></textarea >

    ​{% endfor %}


  </body>
</html>
```

Each of the result `q` is a `list of list` in itself. How can I loop through the individual results and print the entire result of an individual `q` in the textarea?

I tried something like the following using two for loops but my logic is flawed and it displays bogus results (complete newbie in Flask/Html) :

```
{% for q in q1 %}
      {% for q_prime in q %}
    ​    <textarea form="txtArea" name="q_prime" class="form-control" id="q_prime" rows="100" cols="60" placeholder="{{ q_prime }}" style="font-size: 15pt"></textarea >
      {% endfor %}
​{% endfor %}
```

I am attaching two screenshots to make things more clear :

1. This is when I display the entire list i.e. just using 1 for loop :
   [image]
2. And this is when I iterate via the 2nd for loop :
   [image]

So essentially the result set from the 1st screen shot gets printed in different textarea when instead I want the content of a particular output list to be contained in its respective textarea

Comment: how about hand this job to the backend, and just render a single layer list to the template?

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in two ways:

1.loop your list in backends and render template with formatted result.

2.use jinja2 template filter

```
@app.template_filter('instead_loop')
def reverse_filter(s):
    final_str = ''
    for i in s:
        for _i in i:
            final_str += str(_i) + ', '
    return final_str
```

then in the template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>fuck</title>
</head>
    <body>

    <textarea form="txtArea" name="q" class="form-control" id="q" rows="100" cols="60" placeholder="{{ q1 | instead_loop }}" style="font-size: 15pt"></textarea>


    </body>
</html>
```